# Getting length of an array inside a Dictionary Key

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm sure this is a very obvious question but I'm not getting anywhere with it and I've been trying for half an hour or so now.

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` which has keys & values, obviously. Each key stores an array of objects. What I need to do is find a specific array in a key and get the list of the array. The catch is that I don't know the value of the key, I just know it's index. (EG: I know I need to find the array in the 2nd key).

I am almost certain this is a very easy & trivial thing to do but it's escaping me, I've only been doing Obj-C for a short while so not entirely at home with it yet!

Thanks,

Jack.

Comment: You need another type of container as the 2nd key is not well defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `allKeys:` to access the keys of your dictionary.

```
- (NSArray *)allKeys
```

Use as below .

```
    NSArray* dictAllKeys = [dict allKeys];
    if([dictAllKeys count] > 2)
    {
      NSArray* myArrayInDict = [dict objectForKey:[dictAllKeys objectAtIndex:1]];
      // get the length of array in dict at 2nd key
      int length = [myArrayInDict count];
    }
```

Comment: From Documentation: allKeys
Returns a new array containing the dictionary’s keys.

- (NSArray *)allKeys
Return Value
A new array containing the dictionary’s keys, or an empty array if the dictionary has no entries.

Discussion
The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Comment: @ Pierre : Right, they haven't specified the order in documentation,But at least we could check and see the order of keys in `allKeys` array ..

Comment: This worked, thank you :) I've cracked it now, thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The order will probably change if another key/value pair is added, it is a `NSMutableDictionary`.  It is best not to rely on the order of a `NSDictionary` or `NSSet`.

Suggestion: Either use another container that does provide ordering such as `NSMutableArray` or find the item using the dictionary's value arrays, perhaps with `NSPredicate`.